# JS function in external file not recognized

Tags: javascript, html

This is in IE7. It's a corporate setting, so not using IE7 is not an option. I'm stuck with it.

I have a textarea in a form:

```
<textarea name="details" id="details" cols="80" rows="20" onfocus="detailsPrompt('focus')">Enter New Details Here</textarea>
```

There is a javascript file called in the  portion of the html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="askopss.js"></script>
```

In that javascript file is this function:

```
function detailsPrompt(taken) {
if ((taken === 'focus') && (document.getElementById('details').value==='Enter New Details Here')) {
document.getElementById('details').value='';
}
}
```

When I click in the textarea, I expect the value to clear out. Except, nothing happens and this error appears:

> Line: 196
>   Char: 1
>   Error: Object expected
>   Code: 0

line 196 corresponds to the line of HTML with the  tag

I had this problem with another function that was being called "onload" and I solved that by moving the function to a different .js file and then calling that js file in its own  tag at the end of the document. It's not a solution that works for an onclick event, however.

Any idea what the problem is?

edit: included suggestions below, but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

This line:

```
detailsPrompt(taken) {
```

Should read:

```
function detailsPrompt(taken) {
```

While:

```
document.getElementById('details').value
```

won't find your textarea because the textarea *doesn't have an id*.

Give the textarea an id attribute with the value `details`

That said, using a default value of a substitute for a `<label>` is a nasty hack with serious accessibility implications.

Comment: leaving the function off was a dumb move on my part. I know better.

Comment: however, fixing that and giving it an id attribute didn't help